# Variables in CakePHP's models: how to acces them from another controller?

Tags: cakephp, variables, model

What I want to do is the following:

I have a model called "Control":

```
class Control extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Control';
    var $myVariable:

    function getMyVariable() {
        $this->$myVariable = 'hello';
        return ($this->$myVariable);
    }
    function getMyVariable2() {
        $myVariable2 = 'hello';
        return ($myVariable2);
    }
}
```

Then, from another controller I do:

```
class TestsController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Tests';
var $uses = array('Test','Control');

    function index() { //whatever }

    function doStuff() {
         $aux = $this->Control->getMyVariable(); //not working, variable not declared
         $aux2 = $this->Control->getMyVariable2(); //works
}
```

I assumed (probably wrong) that I could declare a variable as a property (or atribute) in a model Class like in any other OO languaje, and access it from other places of the aplication, but I guess it doesn't work like this in CakePHP. Am I missing something? Is there any other way to do this? I mean, to having a variable in a model (which content doesn't come from a table) and acces it from other controllers/views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->$myVariable` is the syntax for "variable variables" (or in this case, *variable properties*). The correct syntax is `$this->myVariable`. CakePHP does not alter [the basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) of PHP OOP.

Setting a variable in a getter is pretty weird though, you should not do that.
Also, if you are using getters, you should make the property `protected` or `private`, otherwise it's somewhat pointless.

Comment: Yeah I'm such a noob! The extra $ was my problem, I'm not so used to OOP in PHP yet. I'm actually not using getters or setters, it was just to put an example of a function. Thank you so much for your quick reply!